# how can I control bfs visitor's termination condition

Tags: c++, graph, boost

for example, I want to bfs for only k steps, or called k level. How can I do it?
Now I know only a little about how to terminate it from [Is it possible to change breadth first search termination condition in BGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15942843/is-it-possible-to-change-breadth-first-search-termination-condition-in-bgl).

I use boost::record_distance solved the problem, but I think it's not the perfect answer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a count of levels and when level equals k steps, you can terminate the bfs.

Comment: but I don't know the bfs level, because I didn't have the queue that used in bfs. Or is there any other way to get the level ?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the first call the BFS in a try .. catch structure

```
try {
  ... call the BFS routine ...
}
catch 
{
   std::cout << "max level reached\n";
{
```

In the visitor contructor, initialize a level counter.

In the visitor, increment the level and throw an exception when the maximkum is reached.

Comment: but I don't know the bfs level, because I didn't have the queue that used in bfs. Or is there any other way to get the level ?